How to prove $(f(X_n))_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$ is a Markov chain?
Question:Let $E$ and $F$ be two countable sets and let $f:E\longrightarrow F$ be a surjective map. Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$ be a Markov chain on $E$ with transition matrix $Q.$ Assume that, for every $a\in F$,and every $x,x^\prime\in E$,the equality
$$\sum_{y\in f^{-1}(a)}Q(x,y)=\sum_{y\in f^{-1}(a)}Q(x^{\prime},y)$$
holds whenever $f(x)=f(x^\prime).$

Show that $(f(X_n))_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$ is a Markov chain on $F$ and
give its transition matrix.

My try:Given $y_{n+1}\in F$,we need to compute:$\mathbb P(f(X_{n+1})=y_{n+1}\mid f(X_0)..f(X_n)):$$$\begin{align}
&\mathbb E[1_{\{f(X_{n+1})=y_{n+1}\}}\mid f(X_0)..f(X_n)]\\&=\sum_{z\in E,f(z)=y_{n+1}}\mathbb E[1_{\{X_{n+1}=z\}}\mid f(X_0)..f(X_n)]\\&=\sum_{z\in E,f(z)=y_{n+1}}\mathbb E[\mathbb E[1_{\{X_{n+1}=z\}}\mid X_0...X_n]\mid f(X_0)..f(X_n)]\\&=\sum_{z\in E,f(z)=y_{n+1}}\mathbb E[Q(X_n,z)\mid f(X_0)..f(X_n)]\\&=\sum_{z\in E,f(z)=y_{n+1}}\sum_{w\in E}Q(w,z)\mathbb E[1_{\{X_n=w\}}\mid f(X_0)..f(X_n)]
\end{align}$$Now we need to determine $\mathbb E[1_{{X_n=w}}\mid f(X_0)..f(X_n)]$,but I am stuck here.
I tried to compute $\mathbb E[1_{\{X_n=w\}}\mid f(X_0)=y_0,..,f(X_n)=y_n]$,but I still have no idea what to do next.
Any help would be appreciated.

Note:This problem comes from Measure Theory, Probability, and Stochastic Processes (Jean-François Le Gall) p343 as an exercise


In the second to last line you have $$\mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{z \in f^{-1}(y_{n+1})} Q(X_n,z)| f(X_0),\ldots,f(X_n)\right].$$
The given equality tells us that on the event $\{f(X_n)=f(w)\}$ we have $$\sum_{z \in f^{-1}(y_{n+1})} Q(X_n,z) = \sum_{z \in f^{-1}(y_{n+1})} Q(w,z).$$
For each $y \in f(E)$, pick a representative $w_y \in f^{-1}(y)$. Then since $f(X_n) = f(w_{f(X_n)})$ by definition, $$\begin{align*} &\mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{z \in f^{-1}(y_{n+1})} Q(X_n,z)| f(X_0),\ldots,f(X_n)\right]\\ &= \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{z \in f^{-1}(y_{n+1})} Q(w_{f(X_n)},z)|f(X_0),\ldots,f(X_n)\right]\\
&= \sum_{z \in f^{-1}(y_{n+1})} Q(w_{f(X_n)},z).\end{align*}$$
Hence $(f(X_n))$ is Markov with transition matrix $Q'$ given by $$Q'(y_1,y_2) = \sum_{z \in f^{-1}(y_2)} Q(w_{y_1},z).$$
Note: the representative elements $(w_y)_{y \in f(E)}$ are arbitrary but what allows the arbitrariness is the equality given.
